# Git rebase only last few commits onto master - ignore the rest

Tags: git

- We have a master branch
- Working on new feature on dev branch a
- I made a pull request from dev branch a to merge with master
- Started working on dev branch b which relies on dev branch a
- merged dev branch a into dev branch b

However now I'm ready to open a PR for dev branch b, so I no longer need it to include the changes in dev branch a.

Is there a way to rebase dev branch b onto master with only the commits made after merging with dev branch a?

Answer (score 0):

After the version 1.7.2 of git, check it with `git --version`.

You can use cherry-pick to select the few commit that you need.

```
git cherry-pick $SHA_FIRST_COMMIT^..$SHA_LAST_COMMIT
```

Use it on dev branch B and select the two sha commit interval that you want to pick from master. those interval are inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
git rebase a b --onto master
```

rebases commits starting from the commit pointed by branch `a`, ending with the commit at the head of `b`, onto `master`.

Comment: If the dev branch A has been merged in local onto master then the commit will be taken as well.